# How do two identical strings not equal each other?

Tags: javascript

Someone sent me this email:

Why do both of these alert to false?

```
alert('a‌' == 'a');
alert('a‌' === 'a');
```

Here's a demo

## [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sQrST/)

Comment: Ha-ha... Seems you write another 'a'-s in other language xD

Comment: Copied and pasted into a file. Viewed with hex editor. Yep, one 'a' on each side is 61 E2 80 8C ('a' + some unicode char).

Comment: E2808C is the Unicode 'Zero Width Non-Joiner' character and it's invisible when not relevant to the text being given. It is, however, quite valid in a string.

Comment: Just a help for a similar problem: one of the two strings could be inside an array (```val1='a'; val2=['a']```); if you log/alert them you'll get the same output, making you think they are the same string. Maybe it'll save some time to someone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this a trick?  Did you generate those `a's` with some special unicode magic?  I deleted the `a's` and re-typed them, and now both alerts show `true`, as they should

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQrST/1/)

Answer (score 17):

The first `a` of each is not actually a simple `a`. If you position the cursor right after it and hit Backspace, you delete "something", and then it returns `true`.

I copied your `a` string, this is what I get when running this code:

```
$a='a‌';
var_dump($a);

string(4) "a‌"
```

See what's wrong here? The string length is 4.

Furthermore, this:

```
echo base64_encode($a);
```

..returns:

```
YeKAjA==
```

When, for a simple string with the letter `a`, it should only be `YQ==`.

The extra character is called a ["ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm).

Answer (score 6):

For the first 'a' console says:

```
'a‌'.charCodeAt(0)
97
'a‌'.charCodeAt(1)
8204
```

8204 seems to be a unicode value for [Zero-width non-joiner](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=unicode%208204&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner&ei=RgkXT9DWJcL54QT9zrSmBA&usg=AFQjCNGGxW-UtdXQ-DbzSD3WDvkyYlb_YQ)

Whilst for the second its:

```
'a'.charCodeAt(0)
97
'a'.charCodeAt(1)
NaN
```

It's natural that different strings are different :).

Comment: What's that? a null character?

Comment: @qwertymk It is called "Zero-width non-joiner" - it is usually used in Arabic languages.